# Python Selenium didn't find Element by ID

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find an input field by Id. The input field looks like

HTML:

```
<input id="hgz" onkeyup="runUpKey('form_hgzii);">
```

Python:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("hgz").send_keys("test")
```

Result:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="hgz"]"}
```

While iterating through all input fields

```
for inputs in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input'):
    print(inputs.get_attribute("id"))
```

Python prints the correct ID, when im changing the code to

```
for inputs in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input'):
    if inputs.get_attribute("id") == "hgz":
        inputs.send_keys("test")
```

it also does not work.

Anyone an Idea?

Comment: Does the element load dynamically? I mean if that loads later using javascript

Comment: Yea it use javascript, it confuse me csuse it find the id while looping through all inputs

Comment: Try changing `get_attribute` to `get` in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code right after opening the page? Maybe the DOM didn't finish loading. Try putting a sleep statement like `sleep(5)` before trying to get element by id

Comment: Already have a sleep for 10 seconds after the button click before. I though something similar if the loop didn't print out the correct ID